# Replicating random normal generated in SAS (rancor) in R, based on the same seed?

Tags: r, sas, random

Given the same seed, is there a way to produce the exact same random normal numbers generated in SAS, using the rannor function, in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make these match, you need two things:

- The seed used to generate the random number
- The formula used to generate the random number

SAS uses for `rannor` (and I think also for `rand`, but I haven't seen confirmation of this), the following algorithm (found in [Psuedo-Random Numbers: Out of Uniform](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/po/25p236.pdf), by Robert Johnson and Hui Liu):

```
rannor_result = (−2* log(U1))**.5*cos(2*constant('pi')*U2)
```

where U1 and U2 are two numbers from the uniform number stream.  (A second number could also be obtained, but that number is discarded as far as I can tell.)

See the following SAS datastep:

```
data test1;
  U1 = ranuni(7);
  U2 = ranuni(7);
  X1 = (−2* log(U1))**.5*cos(2*constant('pi')*U2);
  U1 = ranuni(7);
  U2 = ranuni(7);
  X2 = (−2* log(U1))**.5*cos(2*constant('pi')*U2);
run;
data test2;
  x1 = rannor(7);
  x2 = rannor(7);
run;
```

`test1` and `test2` have identical values for the rannorm numbers.

I doubt that R and SAS share common PRNG algorithms, particularly as the one `rannor` uses is not very good (you should use `rand` which is much, much better, using a Mersenne Twister).  However, you can easily ask SAS to output the seeds it used - as long as you output the RANUNI results.

You can ask SAS to do that in this manner:

```
data rands_uni;
  seed=7;
  do _i_=1 to 10;
    seed1 = seed;
    call ranuni(seed,x1);
    seed2=seed;
    call ranuni(seed,x2);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

From that you could then in R calculate the rannor result (ie, from x1 and x2).  I include the seeds there for reference - perhaps R does have the ability to use them.  The above paper does reference the algorithm SAS used for `ranuni`, but it also states that you cannot replicate it perfectly due to some corrections used (or, perhaps, due to floating point precision issues?).

Answer (score 0):

I test both, it seem it did not.

```
data _null_;
CALL STREAMINIT(1245);
do i=1 to 10;
x2 = rand('NORMAL',0,1);
put x2;
end;
run;
/*
-1.295643934
0.0651085355
-0.391011151
1.1024205822
2.0712099724
-0.296163515
0.898941256
-0.584950901
0.2027164546
-0.986522152*/

set.seed(1245)
df<-rnorm(10,0,1)
df
 [1]  0.41914007 -1.45583361 -1.45588008 -1.01564637 -0.53309914 -0.68360608  0.32590880 
 [8]  0.92256137 -0.05085288  0.29722361
```

Comment: I imagine the user is asking if it's possible to do it _in some fashion_, not if it's possible to do it using the base tools only. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Proc IML;
Call RandSeed(6);
U1 = J(6,1);
U2 = J(6,1);
/* Weibull Distribution */
Call RandGen(U1,"WEIBULL",1.7737152,13.164695);
Print "Weibull Distribution:" U1;
/* Unifrom Distribution */
Call RandGen(U2,"UNIFORM",0,1);
Print "Uniform Distribution:" U2;

Submit/R;
    set.seed(6);
    ## Weibull Distribution;
    U1 <- rweibull(6,1.7737152,13.164695);
    cat("Weibull Distribution:", U1, "\n");
    ## Uniform Distribution;
    U2 <- runif(6,0,1);
    cat("Unifrom Distribution:", U2, "\n");
EndSubmit;

Quit;
```

[image]